# Locbaml localization of .net wpf4 application

Tags: wpf, localization

Have followed every step correctly from this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx

When trying to localize the file using locbaml.exe /parse I keep getting this error -

C:\MyData\Projects\APM V3\DEV-3.5.0\Meridium\Admin\DBUpgMgr2\ImportUtility\DBUpg
radeUI\obj\x86\Debug>

LocBaml.exe /parse DBUpgradeUI.resources.dll /out:DBUpgradeUI.csv

Microsoft (R) Baml Localization Utility 0.0.0.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2005. All rights reserved.

Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\MyData\Projects\APM V3\DEV-3.5.0\Mer
idium\Admin\DBUpgMgr2\ImportUtility\DBUpgradeUI\obj\x86\Debug\DBUpgradeUI.resour
ces.dll' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with
an incorrect format.

Any ideas? I'm using windows 7, visual studio 2010

Also tried this from this link but to no avail - http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/d442b337-2397-4a11-ab52-e0f1b6fc91b9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK found the answer. Download a .net compatible locbaml from this site and then try - works pretty good http://michaelsync.net/2010/03/01/locbaml-for-net-4-0

Answer (score 0):

I also struggeled with LocBaml, downloaded and compiled the code and even started to debug when I ran into the described problem.

My solution was to visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-localize-an-application

The important part I missed was **Copy LocBaml to the bin/Release folder that contains the assembly to be parsed**.

When e.g. LocBaml.exe was copied (in my case to e:\code\LocalizationTest\bin\Debug) I could execute

```
locbaml.exe /parse en-us/LocalizationTest.resources.dll /out:LocalizationTest.csv
```