# Problem generating satellite assembly from CSV (using LocBaml)

Tags: wpf, localization, locbaml

I've been trying to generate a satellite assembly using the LocBaml tool downloaded from [here](http://michaelsync.net/2010/03/01/locbaml-for-net-4-0), but haven't been successful. I'm using the code present in the book "WPF 4 Unleashed". Here is what I'm doing :

- I first created a CSV file:

  ```
  LocBaml /parse ProjectName.g.en-US.resources /out:en-US.csv
  ```

  This step was successful.
- Next I modified the file and saved it as nb-NO.csv
- Now when I try to generate the dll file using

  ```
  LocBaml /generate ProjectName.resources.dll /trans:nb-NO.csv /cul:nb-NO
  ```

  The tool runs, but no resource file is generated (There is no exception).

Am I doing anything wrong? Is the above command not correct?

Comment: Please refer to my another post for the details
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933726/how-does-locbaml-work/49918287#49918287

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `out` parameter. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx) help.

```
LocBaml /generate ProjectName.resources.dll /trans:nb-NO.csv /out:c:\ /cul:nb-NO
```

Comment: I've tried that before. But it doesn't work. The file is not generated

Comment: Are you having the dll and csv in the same folder as LocBaml.exe?

Comment: I used to follow the steps metioned here and it has always worked.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx

Comment: I'm getting error while executing LocBaml.exe /generate en-US/WpfApplication2.resources.dll /trans:WpfApplication2nb-NO.csv /out:c:\ /cul:nb-NO    
It says "Each row must have the 2nd column as the key to the resource"

Comment: how did you edit your csv, does it have something like this as the second column if you open in excel :TextBlock_1:System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock.$Content

Comment: The problem is due to some formatting issue. When we modify the file in excel and save it, then I get the error of "Each row must..." while running locbaml. But the error doesn't come if the file is modified in notepad

Comment: Thanks for your help @anivas. I really appreciate it ! Thanks for the article aswell.